# Using python to find the missing coordinate of a rectangle

Tags: python, math, coordinates, rectangles

**Problem:** ***Given integer coordinates of three vertices of a rectangle whose sides are parallel to coordinate axes, find the coordinates of the fourth vertex of the rectangle.***

I have written the code to answer the problem as follows (but it's not correct):

```
coord_1_x = int(input())
coord_1_y = int(input())

coord_2_x = int(input())
coord_2_y = int(input())

coord_3_x = int(input())
coord_3_y = int(input())

coord_4_x = 0
coord_4_y = 0

if coord_1_x == coord_2_x:
  coord_4_x = coord_3_x
  if coord_2_y > coord_1_y:
    coord_4_y = coord_2_y
  else:
    coord_4_y = coord_1_y
else:
  if coord_3_x == coord_1_x:
    coord_4_x = coord_2_x
    coord_4_y = coord_3_y
    
print(coord_4_x)
print(coord_4_y)
```

Here's some example inputs/outputs that the code should display:

**Example input #1** - *Three vertices given are (1, 5), (7, 5), (1, 10)*

```
1
5
7
5
1
10
```

**Example output #1**

```
7
10
```

**Example input #2** - *Three vertices given are (1, 5), (7, 10), (1, 10)*

```
1
5
7
10
1
10
```

**Example output #2**

```
7
5
```

*Please can someone help me determine the correct code to answer this problem? (I've tried Googling/ reading previous Stack posts but can't find an answer)*

**Note: The code should only use if/else statements, not arrays or loops.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if coord1_x == coord2_x or coord1_x==coord3_x:
    if coord1_x == coord2_x:
           coord4_x=coord3_x
    else:
           coord4_x=coord2_x
else:
    coord4_x=coord1_x
if coord1_y == coord2_y or coord1_y==coord3_y:
    if coord1_y == coord2_y:
           coord4_y=coord3_y
    else:
           coord4_y=coord2_y
else:
    coord4_y=coord1_y
```

Answer (score 2):

Since a rectangle is symmetric, the X and Y coordinates need to appear 2 times in all Points of your rectangle. So you would just need to find the X and Y values that appear **once** in your given points:

```
def getMissingRectanglePoint(A, B, C):
    rectangle = [A, B, C]
    xValues = [p[0] for p in rectangle]
    yValues = [p[1] for p in rectangle]

    missingX = [mp for mp in xValues if xValues.count(mp) == 1][0]
    missingY = [mp for mp in yValues if yValues.count(mp) == 1][0]

    print missingX
    print missingY


getMissingRectanglePoint( (1, 5), (7, 5), (1, 10) )
getMissingRectanglePoint( (1, 5), (7, 10), (1, 10) )
```

Prints:

```
7
10

7
5
```

Comment: And what if rectangle is rotated around its axis?

Answer (score -2):

```
mylist = []
for i in range(6):
    num = input('num: ')
    mylist.append(num)
for i in range(2):
    if mylist.count(mylist[i]) == 2:
        number = ''.join(mylist[i])
        mylist.remove(number)
        mylist.remove(number)


print(mylist)
```

Comment: You missed this requirement in the question: "The code should only use if/else statements, not arrays or loops".